# Contract deploy timeout - web3py & Parity

Tags: parity, web3.py

I'm trying to deploy a contract but it seems like I'm going through a minefield...

When I try to deploy the contract I always get timeout error.

I wrote the contract on remix, and tried both remix compiler aswell as solcjs compiler, but to no avail.

Here is the relevant part of my code

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
rpcc = Web3(HTTPProvider('myserver'))
rpcc.personal.unlockAccount(myaddress, 'password')
abi = json.load(open('mycontract.abi')) # [{"constant":true..."type":"event"}]
bytecode = open('mycontract.bin').read() # 60606040523...4406e0029
contract = rpcc.eth.contract(address=myaddress, abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
contract.deploy()
```

And I always get this error

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='yourhost', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

Even thought it was just slow, but I gave it 600s (10 minutes) timeout and still got the same error...

I searched all over the internet and got nothing useful

Any ideas?

Comment: Your connection looks a little unusual (esp. port 80). How did you start up Parity? Can you give the exact provider setup you used? Do other requests over the connection work, like using `rpcc.eth.accounts` or `rpcc.eth.getBlock('latest')`?

Comment: @carver the "myserver" is only a placeholder, however I am running parity behind an nginx ProxyPass (to restrict IPs and do authentication). Parity is running and sync'd. All other calls are running smoothly, including ``eth.sendTransaction``

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue when connecting with `HTTPProvider` directly to the IP/port that parity opens? (ie~ without the proxy)

Answer (score 1):

On Parity 2.4, contract deployments time out if `web3.eth.defaultAccount` hasn't been unlocked.  Check out docs for the [web3.parity.unlockAccount](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.parity.html#web3.parity.unlockAccount) API.